# Yii CacheDependency based on cache value

Tags: yii, memcached

This seems like a simple thing and should be part of the base code for Yii, but I can't find a solution anywhere.  Here is my scenario.

1) User updates their record (use beforesave to set a cache value, changes with each new save, php unique())

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    Yii::app()->cache->set('userupdate'.$this->id,uniqid());
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

2) User data is cached using the cache value in step one as a dependency in the loadModel function of the model.

```
$model=Users::model()->cache(1800, $dependency)->findByPk($id);
```

3) User views a page that calls to retrieve their data.  Yii evaluates the request to see if the cached valued from step 1 has changed, if it has not pull from cache, if it has pull from db.

While reading this page (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data) it has that function if a file date changes, but not one for it a variable changes.  Any help in this matter would be great as I am at a loss of how to implement this.

NOTE: I need to use cache to hold the variable as I'm running multiple instances of my application and they need shared over each server and all users (thus session won't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fighting with this I found the solution, don't feel it's completely pretty, but it does work.  Any feedback on a cleaner way is much appreciated.

```
    $cache = Yii::app()->cache;
    $key1 = 'userupdate'.$id; //main cache value
    $key2 = '2userupdate'.$id; //will equal main cache when query is cached
    $cache1 = $cache['userupdate'.$id];
    $cache2 = $cache['2userupdate'.$id];

    $dependency = new CExpressionDependency("Yii::app()->cache->get('$key1') == Yii::app()->cache->get('$key2')");
    $model=Users::model()->cache(1800,$dependency)->findByPk($id);
    if($cache1 != $cache2)
        $cache['2userupdate'.$id] = $cache['userupdate'.$id];
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the dependency options is [CExpressionDependency](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CExpressionDependency).  You could compare the currently cached beforeSave value to the value you get from the loadModel call.

Comment: Sounds simple in theory, but this is why I am stumped.  I have tried to capture the current cache value in a value2 during afterFind event and then evaluate them, but this is not working.

Comment: I have gone as simple as this `if($cache1 == $cache2)
        {
            $model=Users::model()->cache(1800)->findByPk($id);
        }else{
            $model=Users::model()->cache(0)->findByPk($id);
        }`

Comment: Ok, found part of the problem, I'm calling a model search for each URL request due to an advanced UrlRule so working to find a way around that.